# Como converter XLSx para CSV em PHP e usar arquivo para gravar no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estou usando um recurso que encontrei para converter um arquivo `XLSX` para `CSV` com a biblioteca `SimpleXlsx` antes de inserir em uma tabela banco de dados mas não estou conseguindo, o que fiz até o momento é isso:

```
// TRANSAÇÃO
try {
    
    // INICIALIZA A TRANSAÇÃO
    $conexao->beginTransaction();   
 
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
  
        $xlsx = new SimpleXLSX($_FILES['Upload']['tmp_name']);

        foreach ($xlsx->rows() as $RegLinhas) {
            
            // RETIRA ESPAÇOS NO INÍCIO E FIM
            $CamposImportacao = trim($RegLinhas);
            
            // RECUPERANDO VARIÁVES PARA ORGANIZAR INSERT
            $IdProcesso = $_POST['IdProcesso'];
            
            // CAMPOS DA FATURA
            $Cartao = $CamposImportacao[0];
            $Portador = $CamposImportacao[1];                   
            $Status = $CamposImportacao[2];
            $DataAtualizacao = $CamposImportacao[3];
            $DataTransacao = $CamposImportacao[4];
            $Valor = $CamposImportacao[5];
            $Estabelecimento = $CamposImportacao[6];
            $TipoTransacao = $CamposImportacao[7];
            
            // INVERTENDO A DATA PARA GRAVAÇÃO
            $DataAtualizacao = implode("-",array_reverse(explode("/",$DataAtualizacao)));
            $DataTransacao = implode("-",array_reverse(explode("/",$DataTransacao)));
            
            // REMOVE O R$
            $Valor = str_replace('R$', '', $Valor);
            // REMOVE O PONTO
            $Valor = str_replace('.', '', $Valor);
            // TROCA VÍRGULA POR PONTO
            $Valor = str_replace(',', '.', $Valor); 
            
            // PERMITIR LEITURA DE LINHAS QUE TENHAM CONTEÚDO       
            if (!empty($IdProcesso)) {

                try {
                    // INSERT
                    $crud = $conexao->prepare("INSERT INTO finItemProcessoCartao (IdProcesso,Cartao,Portador,Status,DataAtualizacao,DataTransacao,Valor,Estabelecimento,TipoTransacao) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");                    
                    $crud->bindParam(1, $IdProcesso, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $crud->bindParam(2, $Cartao, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $crud->bindParam(3, $Portador, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $crud->bindParam(4, $Status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $crud->bindParam(5, $DataAtualizacao, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $crud->bindParam(6, $DataTransacao , PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $crud->bindParam(7, $Valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $crud->bindParam(8, $Estabelecimento, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $crud->bindParam(9, $TipoTransacao, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $Registro = $crud->execute();   
                    
                    // ATUALIZANDO O ESTADO
                    if ($Registro) {
                        $crud = $conexao->prepare("UPDATE finProcessoCartao SET finProcessoCartao.Estado = 'Importado' WHERE finProcessoCartao.IdProcesso = ?");
                        $crud->bindParam(1, $IdProcesso, PDO::PARAM_INT);   
                        $crud->execute();
                    }
                    
                } catch(PDOException $erro) {  

                    // DESFAZ TRANSAÇÃO ATUAL
                    $conexao->rollBack();
                    $erro = $erro->getMessage();
                    $retorno = array('codigo' => '0', 'mensagem' => ' Erro ao inserir registro na tabela. Tente novamente [2]. ::$erro');
                    $conexao = null;        

                    // RETORNO DE MENSAGEM
                    echo json_encode($retorno);
                    exit();             

                }
            // FIM DO IF DE VERIFICAÇÃO DE CONTEÚDO
            }
        // FIM DO FOREACH QUE VARRE O REGISTRO
        }
    // FIM DO IF QUE VERIFICA ENVIO DO REGISTRO
    } else {
        
        $retorno = array('codigo' => 0, 'mensagem' => 'Atenção, você precisa enviar um arquivo CSV para o upload.' );
        echo json_encode($retorno);
        exit(); 
        
    }

    $conexao->commit();
    
// FIM DO TRY
} catch (Exception $e) {    
    
    // DESFAZ TRANSAÇÃO ATUAL
    $conexao->rollBack();   
    $retorno = array('codigo' => '0', 'mensagem' => ' Ocorreu um erro na gravação, tente novamente [1]. ::$erro');              
    $conexao = null;        

    // RETORNO DE MENSAGEM
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();     
}   
    
$retorno = array('codigo' => '1', 'mensagem' => ' Upload do arquivo CSV efetuado com sucesso para o processo: ' . $IdProcesso); 

// FECHA CONEXÃO
$conexao = null;        

// RETORNO DE MENSAGEM
echo json_encode($retorno);
exit();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para converter um arquivo XLSX para CSV em PHP e usar o conteúdo para gravar no MySQL, você pode seguir os seguintes passos:

Instale a biblioteca PHPExcel usando o Composer:

```
composer require phpoffice/phpexcel
```

Carregue o arquivo XLSX usando a classe PHPExcel:

```
$inputFileName = 'arquivo.xlsx';
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
```

Converta o arquivo para CSV usando a função "save":

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
$objWriter->save('arquivo.csv');
```

Abra o arquivo CSV e leia o conteúdo linha por linha:

```
$file = fopen('arquivo.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
   // faça alguma coisa com a linha
}
fclose($file);
```

Conecte-se ao seu banco de dados MySQL e insira os dados lidos do arquivo CSV em uma tabela usando uma consulta INSERT, exemplo com **mysqli**:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha', 'banco_de_dados');

$query = "INSERT INTO tabela (coluna1, coluna2, coluna3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $valor1, $valor2, $valor3);

while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
   $valor1 = $line[0];
   $valor2 = $line[1];
   $valor3 = $line[2];
   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysqli_close($conn);
```